# Run flask app and celery tasks on independent conda environments

Tags: python, celery

I'm new to celery, but I'm wondering whether it is possible to trigger and run celery tasks on a different conda environment that is independent from the flask app. So far I have a running example with *rabbitmq* as broker and *redis* as backend. I pass filepaths to the celery tasks and run operations on the files in the background. Then I pass back the result and show it with flask. But I need to install all the dependencies on my flask environment.

tasks.py: (should run on env1)

```
import torch  # this package is not installed on env2

celery_app = Celery('tasks',
                    broker='amqp://usr:pw@localhost:5672/',
                    backend='redis://localhost/0')
@celery_app.task
def analyze(filepath):
    ...
    return new_filepath
```

app.py: (should run on env2)

```
from tasks import celery_app  # throws error, because torch is not installed

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/a/<path>')
def evoke_task(path):
    task = celery_app.send_task('tasks.analyze', kwargs={'filepath': path})
    return jsonify({}), 202, {'Location': url_for('taskstatus', task_id=task.id)}
```

start workers on env1 and flask on env2

```
(env1) C:\example>celery -A tasks.celery_app worker -l INFO -P threads
(env2) C:\example>flask --app app.py run
```

My example does not work since importing from tasks requires all the dependencies on the flask environment.

It would be great If the flask app could be completely independent from what is happening with the files. Is that possible with celery (and my setup)? If yes, how? If no: what would be other ways to trigger tasks and get results reliably on two independent python processes?

Answer (score 0):

I figured a very simple way to do it :) This works when you want to trigger a Celery task that runs on a different conda environment:

tasks.py: (runs on env1)

```
import torch  # this package is not installed on env2

celery_app = Celery('tasks',
                    broker='amqp://usr:pw@localhost:5672/',
                    backend='redis://localhost/0')
@celery_app.task
def analyze(filepath):
    ...
    return new_filepath
```

app.py: (runs on env2)

```
from celery import Celery
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
# create a new celery instance with same broker and backend
celery = Celery(app.name, 
                    broker='amqp://usr:pw@localhost:5672/',
                    backend='redis://localhost/0')

@app.route('/a/<path>')
def evoke_task(path):
    task = celery.send_task('tasks.analyze', kwargs={'filepath': path})
    return jsonify({}), 202, {'Location': url_for('taskstatus', task_id=task.id)}
```

start workers on env1 and flask on env2

```
(env1) C:\example>celery -A tasks.celery_app worker -l INFO -P threads
(env2) C:\example>flask --app app.py run
```